# O que faz o "out" no C# e qual a diferença do ponteiro?

Tags: c#

Estava jogando [Space Engineers](https://store.steampowered.com/app/244850/Space_Engineers/) e nele é possível adicionar códigos customizados, chamado [`in-game script`](https://github.com/malware-dev/MDK-SE/wiki/Api-Index), em C#. Enfim, me deparei com a necessidade de usar um tal de `out`, mas não entendi o que ele faz e porque ele existe.

---

Uma das funções é exatamente:

```
float Velocidade = 0;

if (!float.TryParse(Argumentos.Argument(1), out Velocidade)) {
      // ...
}

// ...
```

Quando tentei usar o `TryParse` o Visual Studio simplesmente apontou um erro e sugeriu o uso do `out`, ficando `out Velocidade` (ou invés de `Velocidade` ou `&Velocidade`).

O código funcionou. Mas, continuo sem entender o porque o `out` existe e o que de fato ele faz (e qual a vantagem dele), sendo que o C# permite uso de ponteiros, até onde eu tenho conhecimento.

---

Enfim, o que faz o `out` e porque utilizar ele? Porque não utilizar ponteiros?

Comment: O modificador `out` em um parâmetro significa que a finalidade desse parâmetro é a devolução de dados pelo método.